# Removing qualitative features from a dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset comprised of both quantitative and qualitative features. How do I remove the qualitative features from this dataset (For Example: "Auto" dataset) in R?

Comment: The only "qualitative" data in Auto (assuming the guess below about which package you were getting it from is correct) is the name column. Unless of course you were asking for columns that have limited numbers of distinct values such as 'cylinders' or 'years' or 'origin'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following identifies the type of each column, then removes any unwanted data types from the dataframe

```
library(ISLR)

data <- Auto

# Get Data Types of all Columns in the Data Frame
column_types <- sapply(data, class)

# Create a vector to hold all the unwanted data types (Change to what you want)
unwanted_types <- c("factor", "character")

# Remove all the columns which are of the unwanted datatypes
data <- data[, which(!column_types %in% unwanted_types)]

# Get Summary of the DataFrame
summary(data)

mpg          cylinders      displacement     horsepower        weight      acceleration        year           origin     
 Min.   : 9.00   Min.   :3.000   Min.   : 68.0   Min.   : 46.0   Min.   :1613   Min.   : 8.00   Min.   :70.00   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.:17.00   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:105.0   1st Qu.: 75.0   1st Qu.:2225   1st Qu.:13.78   1st Qu.:73.00   1st Qu.:1.000  
 Median :22.75   Median :4.000   Median :151.0   Median : 93.5   Median :2804   Median :15.50   Median :76.00   Median :1.000  
 Mean   :23.45   Mean   :5.472   Mean   :194.4   Mean   :104.5   Mean   :2978   Mean   :15.54   Mean   :75.98   Mean   :1.577  
 3rd Qu.:29.00   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:275.8   3rd Qu.:126.0   3rd Qu.:3615   3rd Qu.:17.02   3rd Qu.:79.00   3rd Qu.:2.000  
 Max.   :46.60   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :455.0   Max.   :230.0   Max.   :5140   Max.   :24.80   Max.   :82.00   Max.   :3.000
```

I would also suggest reading up on all the different data types R uses.